# Angular ng-repeat very slow for 2000 elements in IE8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm writing an Angular based application. It has to support IE8 :-( When I have 2000 two way bindings on the page, loading of the page on IE8 is so slow that the browser actually times out.

Below is a very simple page that illustrates the problem. It creates an array with 2000 objects in JavaScript (not in DOM) and then assigns that array to a variable in the scope.

This works fine in IE9 and Chrome. With 500 two way bindings, IE8 takes a few seconds. However, cutting down the number of two way bindings on the page to less than 2000 would be very hard in my case.

Would greatly appreciate any solutions whereby I can load 2000 two way bindings with IE8 within a few seconds.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="perfModule">
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function Phone(name, snippet) {
            this.name = name;
            this.snippet = snippet;
        }

        var perfModule = angular.module('perfModule', []);

        perfModule.controller('perfCtrl', function ($scope) {
            var phones = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
                phones.push(new Phone('Nexus S', 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'));
            }
            $scope.phones = phones;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="perfCtrl">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
            {{$index}}: <input ng-model="phone.name"> {{phone.name}} - {{phone.snippet}}
        </li>
      </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you really need all the bindings or are there values that just need to be rendered once that cannot change?

Comment: You may want to look into infinite scrolling.

Comment: Also, there is a big difference between 2000 elements and 2000 bindings. This example contains 6001 bindings.

Comment: If you're stuck with IE8 compliance, you might want to look for another framework. Also, maybe check out [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce). Also also, use `track by` on your ng-repeats

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use $scope.phones directly in the for loop instead of assigning it to a new array of phones. This could possibly render the data a bit faster to your screen.